# Sold - a sequence of words

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, word-sequence

1. Moon
2. False
3. Coffee
4. Peace
5. Neutral
6. Stones
7. Hell
8. Private
9. Plane

What is the pattern behind this sequence? How might it continue?

Comment: The pattern is easy. Numbers increase +1  :p

Comment: It might continue with a number followed by a word.

Comment: @Avigrail I think someone's put too much gravy in his ale. What about the words?

Comment: Are the amount of syllables in each word important?

Comment: They each start with a consonant and have at least one vowel.

Comment: @Doge No, not at all.

Comment: @Moose Something much more specific than that! Hint: the order is important.

Comment: Does the interpretation of the words affect the pattern? For example, if "plane" were interpreted as airplane, as opposed to a mathematical definition (point, line, plane), would it change the options for a 10th word and/or ruin the sequence at plane?

Comment: @Roland Good question! The interpretation *is* important: only one of the two meanings of "plane" you mention will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roland is on the right track, but it's

> rhymes

To go through what we have:

> Ought/Naught/Nought (depending on your dialect) -> bought and sold (believe it or not, I thought of it myself and then saw Roland and Echo say it in comments)
>  One -> sun and moon,
>  Two -> true and false,
>  Three -> tea and coffee,
>  Four -> war and peace,
>  Five -> live and neutral (terms from AC current),
>  Six -> sticks and stones,
>  Seven -> heaven and hell,
>  Eight -> state and private (like colleges -- thanks Bailey M from comments),
>  Nine -> line and plane

It might continue with

> Ten -> pencil (pen and pencil)
>  Eleven -> Kell (Kevin and Kell)

Comment: Great job! +1, but I'll hold off on accepting until you've got 8 and also the title.

Comment: Could eight be 'state'?

Comment: Ought -> Bought and sold? At least I was close!

Comment: Try innate in eight

Comment: Nought -> Bought and sold

Comment: Ten - maybe pen and PAPER is better

Comment: @valuable_asset Yes, paper or ink would be better than pencil IMO. Pencil seems too much of a giveaway! Still, the important thing was to spot the pattern, not to continue it. Also, who are Kevin and Kell?

Comment: Kevin and Kell is a webcomic.  It's popular enough to have its own Wikipedia page.  Also it was the most likely thing I could come up with.

Comment: @DaphneB You should have also tried Hell...

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly wrong, but my guess at the riddle's format might not be.

> Each word in the sequence brings common idioms to mind, as well as opposite/counterparts, like Moon and Sun, True and False, etc. The pattern involves idioms with the words in the sequence as well as with their counterparts.
>  For example:
>  *Blood* **Moon** -- True *Blood* -- True/False
>  **False** *Start* -- *Starting* Tee -- Tee(Tea)/Coffee
>  *Cold* **Coffee** -- *Cold* War -- War/Peace
>  *To come in* **Peace** -- *To be in* Charge -- Charge(d)/Neutral

I'll work on some more if this isn't absolutely wrong, but it feels really forced on my end. My next pairings were going to be:

> Sticks/Stones
>  Heaven/Hell
>  Public/Private
>  Train/Plane (vehicles) or Line/Plane (geometry)

Comment: +1; you got halfway there. Was my last comment that big a hint?